# Invalid bind expression type of ANY for column of type Id

Tags: remote-action, omnistudio, vlocity

I have a callable Apex Class with the queryWithBinds method.

```
global with sharing class OmniRemoteAction implements Callable {

    public Object call(String action, Map<String,Object> args){
        Map<String, Object> input = (Map<String, Object>)args.get('input');
        Map<String, Object> output = (Map<String, Object>)args.get('output');
        Map<String, Object> options = (Map<String, Object>)args.get('options');

        return invokeMethod(action, input, output, options);

    }
    private Object invokeMethod(String methodName, Map<String, Object> input, Map<String, Object> output, Map<String, Object> options){
        Boolean result = true;
        try{
            if(methodName.equalsIgnoreCase('queryWithBinds')){
                queryWithBinds(input, output, options);
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            result = false;
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void queryWithBinds(Map<String, Object> input, Map<String, Object> output, Map<String, Object> options){
        String error = '';
        String queryString;
        Map<String, Object> paramMap = new Map<String, Object>();
        List<sObject> queryResults = new List<sObject>();
        try{
            queryString = (String) input.get('queryString');
            paramMap = (Map<String, Object>) input.get('paramMap');
            queryResults = Database.queryWithBinds(queryString,paramMap,AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);
        }catch(Exception e){
            error = e.getMessage() + ' - ' + e.getStackTraceString();
        }
        output.put('result',queryResults);
        output.put('errors', error);
    }
}
```

Through a remote action, I am trying to invoke this from an Integration Procedure. I send a queryString and a set of parameters I added through a Set Values action.

[image: remote action]

The debug would look something like this

```
{
      "ElapsedTime": 388,
      "Type": "Remote Action",
      "Input": {
        "paramMap": {
          "accountIdList": [
            "001Bo000006P49qIAC",
            "001Bo000006RXcLIAW",
            "001Bo000006RRlUIAW"
          ],
          "contactIdList": [
            "003Bo000007P4KXIA0",
            "003Bo000007M7ExIAK"
          ]
        },
        "queryString": "SELECT Id, name, FinServ__Amount__c, Amount_Owing__c, FinServ__AssetsAndLiabilitiesType__c, Category__c, Date_Acquired__c, Net_Value__c, Original_ValueAmount__c, Owner__c, Record_Type_Name__c, Repayment_percent__c, Repayment_Value__c, Term_Months__c FROM FinServ__AssetsAndLiabilities__c WHERE Record_Type_Name__c = 'Asset' AND (FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c IN: accoundIdList OR FinServ__JointOwner__c IN: accountIdList) ORDER BY FinServ__Amount__c DESC Nulls LAST"
      },
      "Status": true
    }
```

I am getting the **Invalid bind expression type of ANY for column of type Id** error. How could I resolve this?

Comment: Please dont paste images in questions. Can you please copy paste the JSON instead and paste it here.

Comment: What is the data type of the `FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c` and `FinServ__JointOwner__c` fields?

Comment: FinServ__PrimaryOwner__c and FinServ__JointOwner__c fields are account lookup fields

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is in this line

```
paramMap = (Map<String, Object>) input.get('paramMap');
queryResults = Database.queryWithBinds(queryString,paramMap,AccessLevel.SYSTEM_MODE);
```

`accountIdList` can technically be only `List<Id>` or `List<String>`, whereas you are passing them as `Object`, thus apex compiler is not able to understand the required datatype there, which can be only `List<Id>` or `List<String>`.

Thus changing this `paramMap = (Map<String, Object>) input.get('paramMap');` line to

```
Map<String, List<String>> paramMap = new Map<String, List<String>>();
paramMap = (Map<String, List<String>>) JSON.deserialize(JSON.serialize(input.get('paramMap')), Map<String, List<String>>.class);
```

Should force the object to convert it to `List<String>` and then your query should work fine.